# Associative values in MySQL result

Tags: mysql, associative

is there a way of using MySQL that allows me to get a result with associative values (like in php´s associative array).

For example:

Moviename: 'The Pianist', Director: 'Roman Polanski', Language: 'English', Actor: 'Adrien Brody' 'Emilia Fox' 'Frank Finlay'.

That is, get all of the matching actors as a single row.
Is this possible, or do i have to stick with:

Moviename: 'The Pianist', Director: 'Roman Polanski', Language: 'English', Actor: 'Adrien Brody'

Moviename: 'The Pianist', Director: 'Roman Polanski', Language: 'English', Actor: 'Emilia Fox'

Moviename: 'The Pianist', Director: 'Roman Polanski', Language: 'English', Actor: 'Frank Finlay'

Comment: And now i have run into another problem. I movie can of course have more than one language to. But when i add another language the results duplicate. In other words the actors are listed two times. And if i add another language (a total of three languages) the actors get listed 3 times each. How do i resolve this? I tried to GROUP_CONCAT the languages to, but that didn't work out as i had planed ;) Is there a way of showing all actors and all languages in one result row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not an associative array - but a list of values belonging to the same group. For this you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), grouping your query by moviename, director and language, like this:

```
  SELECT moviename, director, language, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(actor) AS actors
    FROM movies
GROUP BY moviename, director, language
```